# backing up master disk onto a slave disk in the same machine?

Tags: backup, storage

I'm running Win7 Pro off a 1TB disk with 2 partitions.

I was thinking about buying a 2TB disk and dedicating it to backups.

Ideally, it would maintain a complete duplicate of the master disk (is this called a clone?) and nightly update only the files that have changed.

Is this a rational backup strategy? Is there software that supports this "only new/changed" sort of backing up? I figured that'd be MUCH quicker (after the first run backup)...

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good start, but first, you do not mention what you plan on using as backup software.

Chances are it is not technically a clone, but using an imaging software is one good way to guarantee that you would get back up and running in a hurry if your main drive failed. Most imaging software will allow you to do incrementals (all changes since the last backup), or differential backups (all changes since the last full), but since it is all local, even full backups from one drive to another will be pretty speedy.

The only part that I am not thrilled about is that you have nothing going off-site, meaning your most important documents. I have had a client's office burn to the ground. We will hope that never happens to you, but I would consider adding a service like Carbonite to make sure your files are safe. You could also run an ocassional image to an external drive and store it off-site.

Comment: P.S. I cannot recommend Acronis True Image Home enough. It is just $40 right now, and there is no better imaging product, IMO. http://www.acronis.com/homecomputing/products/trueimage/ You can also add the Plus Pack for $30. The main reason for that for me would be to restore to different hardware down the line. http://www.acronis.com/homecomputing/products/trueimage/